How can I update my UI composable with my viewmodel's mutableState variable
I have copy pasted code from another app that does exactly the same thing and works. The log.i() statement in my code shows that the info changes, but my google map composable doesn't recompose with the new list received from viewModel.getRestaurantList(). The only  thing I find suspicious is that the Log.i() inside the button is always empty, even when the other Log.i(), inside the function in the viewmodel, shows that the list has been updated by the function getRestaurantList in the viewModel. Here is the relevant code:
The composable which serves as a screen:
@Composable
fun SearchScreen(
    myName: String,
    navController: NavController,
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
) {
    val viewModel: LocationViewModel = LocationViewModel(context)
    var user: User = User(myName, 1, 0.0, 0.0)
    ...
}

The composable in the Searchscreen that works but doesn't update (the map loads and I can navigate, but the markers based on the list received do not appear once the button is clicked):
ComposeMapDemo(
    restaurantList = viewModel.restaurantListResponse,
    myName,
    onMarkerClick = { marker, restaurant -> navController.navigate(route = ... },
)

The button which calls the function to update the restaurantList:
Button(onClick = {
    //this log statement is always empty, no matter how often I click on the button
    Log.i("Tag", "restaurantList inside button" + viewModel.restaurantListResponse.toString())
    viewModel.getRestaurantList(restaurant)
}) {
    Text(text = "Scan")
}

The viewmodel:
class LocationViewModel(val context: Context) : ViewModel() {
    var restaurantListResponse: List<Restaurant> by mutableStateOf(listOf())

    fun getRestaurantList(restaurant: Restaurant) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                restaurantListResponse = getRestaurantsListRequest(restaurant)
                //this Log.i shows that restaurantListResponse updates
                Log.i(
                    "Tag",
                    "inside the getRestaurantList function of viewmodel" + restaurantListResponse.toString()
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                errorMessage = e.message.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

The details of the google map composable (I don't think it's relevant):
@Composable
fun ComposeMapDemo(
    restaurantList: List<Restaurant>,
    myName: String?,
    onMarkerClick: (Marker, restaurant) -> Boolean,
) {
    val currentOnMarkerClick by rememberUpdatedState(onMarkerClick)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState()
    val markerState = rememberMarkerState()

    SideEffect {
        if (restaurantList.isEmpty()) return@SideEffect
        val restaurant = restaurantList[0]
        val lat = restaurant?.latitude ?: return@SideEffect
        val lng = restaurant?.longitude ?: return@SideEffect
        val latlng = LatLng(lat, lng)
        markerState.position = latlng
        cameraPositionState.position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(latlng, 500f)
    }

    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight(0.5F)
            .fillMaxWidth(0.75F),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {

        for (restaurant in restaurantList) {
            if (restaurant.open == false) {
                continue

            } else {
                Marker(
                    icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE),
                    state = MarkerState(restaurant.position),
                    title = "${restaurant.name}",
                    onClick = { currentOnMarkerClick(it, restaurant) },
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


In your view model, you use this:
var restaurantListResponse: List<Restaurant> by mutableStateOf(listOf())

While using the delegate by to simplify access to the variable is good practice while inside a composable, doing this in the view model will hide the MutableState from Compose. Since Compose only sees a plain List and doesn't know about the underlying State, it cannot observe the State for changes so it will never trigger a recomposition when that State changes.
If you change that variable to directly hold the State, it should work:
val restaurantListResponse: MutableState<List<Restaurant>> = mutableStateOf(listOf())

Everywhere where you access that variable you need to add .value to it.
There are several drawbacks with this, though. First of, this State now becomes writeable from outside the view model. You should probably make it private and add another variable that exposes this just as a State instead of MutableState. However, you shouldn't even use MutableStates in your view model in the first place. A lot of old documentation and sample code still recommends this, but best practices have shifted over time and to avoid some nasty edge cases of this approach the preferred way to do this now is to use a MutableStateFlow:
private val _restaurantListResponse = MutableStateFlow<List<Restaurant>>(listOf())
val restaurantListResponse: StateFlow<List<Restaurant>> = _restaurantListResponse.asStateFlow()

In your view model you can change the value like this (also update the log statement):
_restaurantListResponse.value = getRestaurantsListRequest(restaurant)

And in your compose code you will have to convert the Flow into a State first before passing it to ComposeMapDemo:
val restaurantList by viewModel.restaurantListResponse.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

Note that this needs the gradle dependency androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose.

Thank you very much! You're a Godsend. The compose map updates. Now I just have to fix what it updates to...
